# How to add overall data to group by category chart in R?

Tags: r, data-visualization, ggplot2, boxplot

i have a (ggplot) chart whit multiple data grouped by factor column. I also would like to add an "overall" group to it. Is there an easy way to do this?

For example i want to extend this plot with a overall boxplot

```
p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(factor(cyl), mpg))

p + geom_boxplot()
```

regards,
Ákos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you meant by overall?

```
library(ggplot2)
data(mtcars)

p <- ggplot(mtcars, aes(factor(cyl), mpg))
p + geom_boxplot() + geom_boxplot(aes('overall', mpg))
```